# Do I need to free the result from ptsname()?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, gnu, pty

When I call `ptsname()` I get a `char*` back.

The manpage doesn't specify its linkage, ownership or lifetime, but valgrind is showing that it's causing a leak (with `--leak-check=full`).

```
==46958== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 41 of 65
==46958==    at 0x10010FEBB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==46958==    by 0x1003F9682: ptsname (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==46958==    by 0x10001BA5F: startJob(childproc*) (unix-base.cc:211)
==46958==    by 0x100019CAB: stepChild(childproc*, std::__1::function<bin::Job* (bin::Job*)>) (unix-base.cc:281)
==46958==    by 0x100018F2C: bin::runJobs(std::__1::function<bin::Job* (bin::Job*)>, int) (unix-base.cc:350)
==46958==    by 0x1000027FC: pmain() (bin.cc:65)
==46958==    by 0x100003787: main (bin.cc:90)
```

However, upon `free()`-ing the result I get the usual un-`malloc`'d error:

```
bin(46690,0x7fff76531000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb35af00f90: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
./bootstrap.sh: line 41: 46690 Abort trap: 6           bin/bin
```

Is this just a leak in the internal implementation of `ptsname()` on this platform, or should I be (somehow) freeing the result?

Comment: `ptsnmame` is nonreentrent as it returns a static storage, consider using the reentrent version `ptsname_r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library allocates that memory, and the documentation says the library may reuse that memory, so you should **not** free it.

> On success, `ptsname()` returns a pointer to a string in static storage which will be overwritten by subsequent calls. This pointer must not be freed. On failure, a `NULL` pointer is returned. 
>   <sub>[The man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ptsname)</sub>

You should ignore this valgrind warning. You can tell valgrind to ignore it for you.

> **`--ignore-fn=<name>`**
>   Any direct heap allocation (i.e. a call to `malloc`, `new`, etc, or a call to a function named by an `--alloc-fn` option) that occurs in a function specified by this option will be ignored. This is mostly useful for testing purposes. This option can be specified multiple times on the command line, to name multiple functions.
>   <sub>[The man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/valgrind)</sub>